# How to avoid gap between Quick launch and footer in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, css, custom-masterpage

I have used [this link](http://www.eliostruyf.com/sticky-footer-solution-for-sharepoint-2013/) for setting the footer, it's working fine. I do not want to change it.
I have provided some background color to quick launch, but when content is less than the page height, a gap appears in between the quick launch and footer, how can I avoid it. Please refer the below image:
[image]

Anyone having any idea, please share.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could try changing the height property of the Navigation Box to achieve your aim:


<style type="text/css">
/*Change QuickLaunch Height */
#sideNavBox
{height: 100px;}
</style>

Comment: I cannot add the height in pixel, as I want it to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

That depends largely on your masterpage and your stylesheet. From your screenshot it looks almost as if the 35px bottom-padding of #s4-bodyContainer is causing this gap (assuming that this value in your stylesheet is not different from the default value).

You could try that:

`#s4-bodyContainer {
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say it as an answer, but it is a workaround that worked for me. here it is:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#sideNavBox").css("height",$(".footer").position().top-$("#sideNavBox").position().top-40);
});
```